# Compute the gradient of Function Defined by Integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, gradient-descent, gradient-flows

I would like to know how to compute the gradient of Function Defined by Integral

For example, Let $\displaystyle f(x(t),y(t))=\int_{0}^{k}g(x(t),y(t))\rm{d}t$ be function and $t\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
$$\nabla f(x(t),y(t))=?$$
How can I compute the gradient of that function with respect to $t$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: In the integral, $t$ is a variable of integration, so it shouldn't also be a parameter of $f$.

Comment: For starters, the left-hand side is not a function of $t$. You need to understand clearly what this question is actually about. The input to $f$ is a pair of functions of $t$ on the interval $[0,k]$.